# Content Security Policy and Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps, eval, content-security-policy

I am using CSP and all is going well. I allow my own inline scripts using a nonce but now I've got a problem with Google Maps.

I've searched everywhere but all SO questions are about Chrome extensions whereas I'm building a website that uses Google Maps.

I get these 2 errors in the console

> Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is
>   not an allowed source...
>   Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string
>   as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source...

I've seen also about using a sandbox but am unsure how to do this. Does anyone know how to do this?

Do I add unsafe-eval (which i don't want to do) to my CSP headers just for specific pages and if so, will the whole site be compromised?

Answer (score 0):

Adding unsafe-eval is not encouraged for any script.
Check out this I/O from Google, it will definitely help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GBxv8SaX0gg

Comment: your problem most likely is inline scripts though. hope this video helps.

Comment: So this question remains un-answered. How does one use Google Maps API with no `unsafe-eval`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.

CSP has strict rules that must be kept in mind when writing javascript and you can't make 3rd party libraries that weren't designed with CSP in mind work without changes.

There's a few options:

1. (**Ideal**) You get Google to update the code so it works nicely under CSP (including having them publish a reccomended policy set necessary for embedding their code in your page).
2. (**Practical**) You relax the policy for that page only, sacrificing all of the benefits of CSP in exchange for the ability to use that library.
3. (**Complex**) You copy the javascript to your own server, use an automated formatter to try and make the uglified code readable, and patch the code yourself to avoid the eval (this may not be "allowed" depending on how google licensese their code).